# How to build and run multiple main cpp files in CodeLite IDE that are in different Projects or within same projects?

Tags: c++, codelite

I have a simple codelite project structure as follows:

[image]

All of the three main.cpp files are independent. I just want to keep it that way as I am not building a typical c++ project rather, I want to use CodeLite to compile, run and test one cpp file to solve some algorithmic puzzles online.

However, when I run `p2/src/main.cpp`, `p1/src/main.cpp runs`, and when I do the same with `p3/src/main.cpp`, `p1/src/main.cpp` runs again.

Basically, I am not able to build and run other codes except `p1/src/main.cpp`.

Comment: What you seem to want is a single *workspace* with three different *projects*.

Comment: yes, is it possible?

Comment: Yes it seems to be possible. I don't know how to set it up though as I don't use CodeLite myself. Check the `File` and `Workspace` menus to see if you can create new projects in the existing workspace.

Comment: Infact, as shown in the image, p1, p2 and p3 are the three projects inside the Deleteme2 workspace

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not late to help you, if so, i hope it helps somebody else.
I was struggling the the same thing, but i manage to do it, here's the path:

[Right Click on the cpp(or whatever you've named it) workspace, on the third option there's NEW with an arrow, inside the arrow click on the second option *New Workspace folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pggQy.png)

[Name it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag6Ug.png)

[Right Click on the Workspace to create your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l45K9.png)

[and it's done you can have as many projects as you want and all of them gonna run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAfUi.png)

I hope i helped.